# ¿Problema para actualizar registro con combobox php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando la actualizacion de un registro en mi BD mendiante `<select>` pero no me funciona.

seguimientoServicio.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <form method="POST" action="actualizarSeguimiento.php">
    <label>Situacion: </label>
        <select type="selec" name="situacion[]" id="situacion">
            <option value='".$situacion."'>Finalizado</option>
            <option value='".$situacion."'>Fallido</option>
            <option value='".$situacion."'>Cancelado</option>
            <option value='".$situacion."'>Programado</option>
            <option value='".$situacion."'>Realizando</option>
        </select>
   </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

actualizarSeguimiento.php

```
<?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin123", "database");

    $servicio_No = $_POST["servicio_No"];
    $situacion = $_POST["situacion"];

    mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE servicio SET situacion = '$situacion'   WHERE servicio_No = '$servicio_No'") or die("ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR");

   mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Tu problema es el name del select, en lugar de "situacion[]" dejalo solo como "situacion".

Comment: ya lo hize asi y no me funciona lo malo es que no muestra errores pero no actualiza

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que a tu página actualizarSeguimiento.php están llegando esos párametros?

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: la verdad no estoy seguro de igual modo sigue sin servir

Comment: que no actualiza el registro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Tu etiqueta `<head>` está sin cerrar y tu etiqueta `</body>` está sin abrir.

  ```
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="actualizarSeguimiento.php">
      <!-- Código de tu formulario -->
     </form>    
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Tal y como defines el `action` de tu formulario, tu **actualizarSeguimiento.php** tiene que estar en la misma carpeta que **seguimientoServicio.php**. Si está en otra carpeta tendrías que especificarlo.
- Yo quitaría los corchetes del atributo `name` del `select` -> `name="situacion"` a no ser que lo que busques es crear una selección múltiple.
- ¿La variable `$situacion` de tu `<option>` de donde proviene?
- ¿De donde proviene `servicio_No` que recuperas por `POST`en actualizarSeguimiento.php -> `$servicio_No = $_POST["servicio_No"];`
- ¿Por qué todas las opciones le pasas la misma variable para el atributo `value`? Creo que la idea sería que el valor fuese distinto según que opción elijan.
- Te recomiendo que para recuperar valores con $_POST uses la siguiente función `$situacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['situacion']);` Puedes encontrar más información de esta función [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).
- Si no tienes claro si tus valores están pasando a actualizarSeguimiento de manera correcta, puedes añadir un `echo $situacion` al final de ese mismo fichero para ver que valor tiene la variable y poder depurar errores.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, pero necesitaras algo parecido a esto, considerando que necesitas setear la variable `$servicio_No` previamente.

seguimientoServicio.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="actualizarSeguimiento.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="servicio_No" value="<?php echo $servicio_No ?>" />

            <label>Situacion: </label>
            <select name="situacion" id="situacion" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="Finalizado">Finalizado</option>
                <option value="Fallido">Fallido</option>
                <option value="Cancelado">Cancelado</option>
                <option value="Programado">Programado</option>
                <option value="Realizando">Realizando</option>
            </select>
       </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Se necesita setear `servicio_No`, ya que es lo que recibes para hacer la actualización en tu query, tambien asumiendo que el campo `situacion` de la tabla `servicio` es alfanumérico

actualizarSeguimiento.php

```
<?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin123", "database");

    $servicio_No = $_POST["servicio_No"];
    $situacion = $_POST["situacion"];

    mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE servicio SET situacion = '$situacion'   WHERE servicio_No = '$servicio_No'") or die("ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR");

    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: yo lo puse todo y no sale completo como hago para que lo veas

Comment: sigue sin funcionar